# Comparing representation of female subjects from past and current consensus statements

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I am comparing the number of female subjects represented in studies for a consensus statement from 5 years ago, to a current statement.
I have counts of female representation for each statement broken down into categories of 0%, >0-20%, >200-40%, >40-60%, >60-80%, >80-100%. (see below).

Is there are way to compare whether there has been a statistically significant change in any of these categories between the 2 statements?

[image]